# How to respond to wrong user command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

If user types `/foo` and that command does not exist, how do I send the message saying "This command does not exist"?

This is maybe pretty simple but I'm bit confused.

If you need more info please comment.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to parse every command that starts with your token (/ here). And if what comes after the / is not in your list of commands, you return "This command does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) event (Note that the order of arguments is reversed on the async branch, compared to the documented rewrite branch) that will be called if there if a `CommandError` is raised.

You can then check in that [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) if the error is a [`CommandNotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound) error and handle it accordingly:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "No such command")
    else:
        raise error
```

This assumes you are using the `discord.ext.commands` extension to write your commands (which you should).