# Just want a reply when u enter a command wrong

Tags: discord.py

I'm not the most knowledgeable with discord.py, I have been doing research on coding following what other people do and say, but it comes to the point where i now need to ask for help.
As i said, I don't know much, all i know is what I've written, all i want to know is when u enter a command wrong, it replies with "what is that". what i have entered doesn't work,

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please pass in all requirements :rolling_eyes:.')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You dont have all the requirements :angry:")
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotFound):
        await ctx.semd("what is this :face_vomiting:")
```

just wondering if anyone can help, because i am new with this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrong commanf'? What conditions make a command wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond to wrong user command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121740/how-to-respond-to-wrong-user-command-in-discord-py)

Comment: "wrong command" do you mean it doesn't exist? missing argument? invalid argument? http error?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
    await ctx.send("what is this :face_vomiting:")
```